# python requests return file-like object for streaming

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I have created a requests object like this:

```
 obj.mp3 = requests.get('http://foo.com/bar.mp3', stream=True)
```

I thought that I could just feed this `obj.mp3` object into any audio player that expects a file or an URI, obviously this idea is wrong: nothing played. Below are the full code:

```
#views.py

class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'song.html'

    def get_object(self):
        obj = super(ArticleDetailView, self).get_object()

        #code to store mp3 url in obj.mp3 and other stuff

        if obj.mp3:
            obj.mp3 = requests.get(obj.mp3, stream=True).content
        return obj

#song.html
<div class="audio">
  <audio src={{ article.mp3 }} type="audio/mpeg"> 
</div>
```

What is the correct way of treating return from `requests` as something that I can stream with a player? I know at least I can write the `obj.mp3` to a file, then just point the player to the file location, but I am trying to avoid write the file to disk.

Thanks,

Answer (score 29):

There's an attribute [Response.raw](https://2.python-requests.org/en/v1.1.0/api/#requests.Response.raw), which is already a file-like object.

```
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
resp.raw # is what you need
```

Using `io.BytesIO(resp.content)` is not preferable since behind the scenes you're reading the same amount of data twice (also memory-wise): accessing `resp.content` reads everything from the network stream, then `io.BytesIO(resp.content)` is allocating again the same amount of memory, and then you read it from BytesIO object.

Comment: Note that [`Response.raw`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.Response.raw) will not respect transfer encodings as documented [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#raw-response-content). Therefore, using `raw` might be wrong depending on the web server.

Comment: After reading [issue #465](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/465), I'm not sure if the problem mentioned in my last comment still exists.

Comment: Looks like you can add `resp.raw.decode_content = True` to fix it.

Answer (score 10):

Look into the [io module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/library/io.html) for using file-like objects.

Probably you could use `io.BytesIO` which you can initialize with the `Response.content`. Then instead of list of bytes you get a file-like object.

```
import io
resp = requests.get(url, stream=True)
obj.mp3 = io.BytesIO(resp.content)
```

Comment: after hours of trying to figure out, i tend to conclude that this is not at all possible: django template expect a string, in particular for any audio player, the string needs to either represent an URL, or a path pointing to the media. however both yours and mine code return an object. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Django's responsibility is to generate the HTML code that is then interpreted by the browser.  The browser is what needs to be streaming the audio.  You need to pass the mp3 url through Django templates that a player like http://www.jwplayer.com/ can then stream on the client side.