# Zipfile can't open a file-like object streaming in request.raw

Tags: python, python-requests, python-zipfile

When I want to decompression a zipfile from internet, there is a error like `zipfile.badzipfile: file is not a zip file`.
here is my code:

```
response = requests.get('www.example.com/somefile.zip', stream=True)
response.raw.decode_content = True
with zipfile.ZipFile(response.raw)as zip_file:
    # do something.
```

PS: Because this zipfile is very large, I don't want to waste memory, so I didn't use `io.BytesIO(resp.content)` as there [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715298/python-requests-return-file-like-object-for-streaming) says.

Comment: A streaming object will result in a partially complete file, which wouldn't work for a zipfile. You may get lucky by downloading in the exact right blocks for a zipfile, but that is unlikely.

Comment: @9769953 - would this work for compressed tar files?

Comment: I don't know. You would need to look up the details of tar files and how e.g., Python handles them.

Comment: @jakub, it should work. Gzip and Tar are both “streamable”; in Unix you can do something like `cat file.tar.gz | gzip -dc | tar -x -f -`. Tar stands for Tape ARchive, and was intended to extract or add files as the tape ran.