# Download pdfs and join them using python

Tags: python

I have a list, named links_to_announcement, of urls for different pdfs.

How do I download them and join them together? My code generated a corrupt pdf which doesn't open in pdf reader at all.

```
with open('joined_pdfs.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    for l in links_to_announcement:
        response = requests.get(l)
        f.write(response.content)
```

Comment: not really. I need to download them first.

Comment: Why do you write ALL downloaded files into the same PDF file? That's not how PDF merge works.

Comment: I need to create a compilation. download the pdfs from a list and create a mega pdf file.

Comment: Writing them all to the same file is not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many file formats have a specific and structured format (rather than being simply lines of arbitrary text) and appending them isn't sufficient!

Instead, in this (writing a PDF) and with many other formats, it's necessary to rewrite them with something that understands their context

For a simple example, if two CSVs were blindly appended, the second CSV's header would be spliced into the middle of the new document and any nonexact columns wouldn't parse correctly or be misinterpreted, even if the corrupt line was removed

`file1.csv`

```
colA,colB
1,2
```

`file2.csv`

```
colC,colD,colA
3,4,5
```

blindly appending the two files

```
colA,colB
1,2
colC,colD,colA
3,4,5
```

how should this document be interpreted?

Instead, a context-aware parser can merge the documents correctly

```
colA,colB,colC,colD
1,2,,
5,,3,4
```

[As suggested by **@esqew**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75197726/download-pdfs-and-join-them-using-python#comment132696216_75197726), PDF files can be merged with logic like [Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

You show how to download the files, but it's probably significantly faster to unpack each web request into a `BytesIO` and combine them all in memory ([python requests return file-like object for streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715298/python-requests-return-file-like-object-for-streaming))
NOTE this will frustrate attempts to restart after a failed request, and you should consider writing each PDF to disk intermediately and checking if you have the file in your local cache before downloading again if you find frequent failed requests

```py
import requests  # aiohttp might be better to asyncio.gather()
from pypdf import PdfMerger

merger = PdfMerger()

with open("links_to_announcement.txt") as fh:
    for url in fh:
        r = request.get(url, stream=True)
        # TODO error handling: .raise_for_status(), backoff, etc.
        r.raw.decode_content = True  # possibly fix encoding issues
        merger.append(r.raw)  # probably an io.BytesIO

merger.write("combined.pdf")
merger.close()
```